# UIToolbar initWithFrame auto size?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have noticed that in order to create a UIToolbar programmatically you need to set its size, for example with initWithFrame.  Is there some way to have it auto compute the size so that on future (past?) versions of the OS everything will be the right size?  I am hesitant to effectively hard code the size of the toolbar.

Thanks!

Comment: iOS does a terrible job with this as of iOS 5. Calling [toolbar sizeToFit] stretches the entire width of the view which is just wrong. Only solution is to get all the widths of the bar button items and then set that toolbar width from that, but that's problematic because you can't get the width of system bar button items.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can extend the UIToolbar-Class and then always instantiate your custom toolbar.

```
@interface CustomToolbar : UIToolbar {
    …
}
- (id)initWithFullSize;
```

and the implementation like:

```
- (id)initWithFullSize {
   self = [self initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height)];
   return self;
}
```

and finally:

```
CustomToolbar *myToolbar = [[CustomToolbar alloc] initWithFullSize];
```

… something like this should do it.

Comment: Just edited the code a little bit to clarify what i mean exactly. Hope it helps you.